# Compare string (date) in sqLite DB in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am storing date(in yyyy-MM-dd format) as a string in database.

And now i would like get all the records from the database wherever the date is greater than todays date.

Also i tried to do it using casting,but still didn't work out for me.

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE CAST(valiDate AS DATETIME) >= ('2103-09-16').
```

Let me know in case i'm doing something wrong here.

Any solution is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString *s_tody=[dateformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [self databaseOpen];
    NSArray *temp=[[NSArray alloc]init];
    NSString *s=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from Task WHERE date > '%@'",s_tody];
```

Comment: If you have any query,please tell me

Comment: If this good then please accept this as a answer & give up vote.

Answer (score 1):

If you want DB queries, you are better off using NSDate. SQLite stores the date as the number of seconds since 1/1/1970, so the comparisons are very efficient. Using strings you have string comparisons which are notoriously expensive.

You can store a date in the database like this:

```
float dateToStore = [theDate timeIntervalSince1970];
```

You can retrieve it like this:

```
NSDate *retrievedDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:numberFromDB];
```

You can filter your query results like this:

```
float dateToQuery = [theDate timeIntervalSince1970];
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.date > %@", dateToQuery];
```

Comment: If dateToQuery is float, query string should be %f.

Answer (score 0):

First you will get the date of your system using below code.....

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *currentdate=[dateformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

now you can compare your current date to your database storedate using below lines.

Code for your database.

```
    databaseName = @"youdatabase.sqlite";

documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

documentsDir = documentPaths[0];

databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

   if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from table WHERE date > '%@'",currentdate];;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

convert utcStr to date

```
+(NSDate*) dateWithUTCStr :(NSString *)utcDateStr{

    double timeInterval = [utcDateStr doubleValue];
    timeInterval = timeInterval / 1000;

    return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
}
```

convert date to utc

```
+(NSTimeInterval) UTCWithDate:(NSDate *)date{

    return [date timeIntervalSince1970]*1000;
}
```

enjoy coding...